# The meet of two minimal generators of a stable ideal in a polynomial ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, lattice-orders, polynomial-rings

Let $k$ be a field and let $R$ be the polynomial ring $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. Let $I$ be a monomial ideal of $R$. We say that $I$ is stable if it satisfies the following "exchange property":  for every monomial $m\in I$ and index $i<max(m)$, the monomial $x_im/x_{max(m)}\in I$, where $max(m)$ is the largest index of a variable dividing $m$. Basically, you can exchange the variable with the largest index appearing in $m$ with something with smaller index and still remain in the ideal $I$.

It is known that there is a unique function $g:M(I)\rightarrow G(I)$, where $M(I)$ is the set of monomials in $I$ and $G(I)$ is the set of minimal generators of $I$, such that $m=g(m)c(m)$ for some $c(m)$ with $max(g(m))\leq min(c(m))$, where min is defined similarly as to the max. Roughly speaking, you want to order the variables of $m$ as $x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_n^{a_n}$, and then start scanning $m$ from left to right until you hit a minimal generator of $I$, and call that generator $g(m)$.

I was reading the paper of Peeva on the existence of a DG algebra structure on the Eliahou-Kervaire resolution, you can find that paper [here](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272332/1-s2.0-S0021869300X01317/1-s2.0-S0021869396902938/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEIL%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQCzDCBRcSr00n3OxKL%2B9iki2J9PRpclX%2BYKrkGWvJcAjAIgeP6hWIjk8S8NG1ObHvDm5g%2F0uhb8jqJzsWyKLRO7kHwqswUIexAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDKFEqRpB8%2Bkx5aukVSqQBeveB94y1epZX5wf4b5zzczRiGLlXywK0aME5ECBn6cOgo%2BR0ZyJvAKn2OlCBiARAlbuVwI%2BXkz9HwLlZFvoriHDkqBOCgEZHjrPM4Z6rsyZ3TJIhudZQkJDN0FTvHPvGI1SIm9WOfXgOKkeGOiO3Gy64bNTan2Nem3cb73XankLiRkQwzZ5nGYf6%2BCafaJ8%2BV8yjJZtyGUitXrm3EIB5TC%2B%2FxnEitWiwkxvLu7KSXrCLa08IYerG%2FFboh97m7DfEAF4t1M2u9IH78zxnk%2FVEAnuQZbUMHfpucgEkNcmluVQvxp4PqwCR44EPz7MokzCtUe%2B2XDoX4G6dWwpxPVxSWEG6xqawg8W6tcV0DiEeADMnRHnpEUjqeM2McB9KvKQd6OZtOL2RmapFiEPaPRQ0p6RRiBdtF97pekdyZJVsJyIWlZaWyay73F%2FSPAlS8hxBp%2Bt2gb0Z8WGJ6Y%2Fw0PXmjSEwRlyJruSyUGPoqVrRkL4rPo%2F0LD7bvg%2Fk%2BRCYBg76dMkpZuCUKVqtt%2BmB0YUPJxBjc%2BjcXOjjp%2BBlOHIEG9GD3wbDyRPUSdhCW7LbBhLumTjRoDEUGpRaLY1%2BiATc3xjDagKWVVyfQY6cKMm79sS4RPgJWiC9njGkYgxfCz6XCtv24A9VJuLFDOj7PPwMQi%2FiQixMfcJws9I145Z6FFAFUwS70w1pApLl08mDdDcbxnRIM3PgSg4qDm0Zq%2FV1YVKyeTa%2B6XD9WDqCSBVHuL2pnpja28OyvUYpLes5xvFZD2eawrt%2F7U%2FnGrxQaPtIeSilWsA5HzAu2oyrIHW6JRQQ2Q%2FxrOsZLVKFkRw7q2V72W7DilPRASBi7J5%2B6QymQtQ7fABSls6i10O1%2BGpiLFYMLHNgKIGOrEBa%2FJKwLRo22j%2BnPkY75nYyEQT%2B7cbYB8mgFjDOjGln8cTtReLExT3VFddO57bTq5m5Kas2fVxkaCb8CdsielJZOctcNjqNfyu7CT6z%2FGSrdrC5t0wKxtZEjJldKlIp13ROz5RzUiYskKZ4yOpwRHFTFDF43faEq%2FlBQByTppB98XZgCj6NzwQs9691BohURKbCgSnZhoSJE4pTtYXmLdybQY8ewd8u07MOaWSRE%2BuxEMq&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230419T181728Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYUTTXWR4A%2F20230419%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=c2bea295a5f08e86a116e2a46fd60f31ce88126713a23ff42351ca76b81929e5&hash=585c26c11b05188139582114309b5c86a8e04beb23b269f71bc1e4dd5a9f469e&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0021869396902938&tid=spdf-3d1d77bd-8d6b-4ebf-9c64-39e60b13dc5d&sid=9a4aed3178b4e749ed0be8984ebe82a56b56gxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=0f15520c07555c505e5f53&rr=7ba725003c85276f&cc=us). In this paper, she takes two minimal generators of $I$, say $a$ and $b$, and defines the $I$-meet of $a$ and $b$ to be the element $g(lcm(a,b))$. Because of the terminology she uses, it makes me think there is a lattice hiding behind the scenes. I know about the lcm-lattice of a monomial ideal, and I do not think it is that one.

So my question is, do you see a lattice that would justify the terminology that Peeva is using in this paper?